# Escaping columns with special chars in SQL JDBC

Tags: sql, csv, jdbc

I got a csv file that I want to import with the [CsvJdbc](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/) driver. I can´t change the csv file, as it is an export from an extern program.

Unfortunately the columns got [] around their name, like `[organisation_id]`

When I want to query the columns, I got a syntax error as `[`, `]` chars are not supported. How can I escape them?

N.B. I already tried `\\[organisation_id]\\`, `\[organisation_id\]`, `//[organisation_id//]`, `/[organisation_id/]`

Comment: do you mean that the columns are wrapped in square brackets in your CSV or in your database?

Comment: Wrapped around my CSV headers. Note that I use a csvjdcb driver that reads a csv as a database table.

Comment: @JacobvanLingen You have to look into the documentation of your driver to get the most correct answer. But most likely that is not possible at all. (You can try quotes, but its still a bad idea; Like "[organisation_id]")

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer: Documentation is not that big, The CsvJdbc driver has been made by a few people, nothing is written for specific things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must strip away the [] before you use them in your SQL. There are certain chars that are not supported in many (all I know of) SQL Systems.

So, you may not name a column `[name]`. There is no escape from that. You must remove it and use `name` instead.

(Please be aware that this only goes for table and column NAMES. in the CONTENT of a column, you must place quotes around the texts like `"value with [] is ok"`)

After some read I can say that sometimes its allowed to use "" to escape column names as well, so `"[organisation_id]"` might sometimes be allowed.

Comment: Ok thx for quick response. I am lazy, so I will use Select * From ... as the getters do support the brackets :D.

Comment: It's not "*sometimes*" that a `"` is allowed to quote identifiers with non-standard characters: that's the rule of standard (ANSI) SQL and all DBMS support that.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is solved by CsvJdbc Feature Request #55, "Allow double-quoted column names, column aliases,table names" ( http://sourceforge.net/p/csvjdbc/feature-requests/55/ ) that is included in the latest CsvJdbc version 1.0-17.

Column names including special characters can now be used with double-quotes around them in SQL statements.  For example,

```
SELECT "[organisation_id]", "foo bar", "< 5 seconds" as HELLO FROM sample
```

This is the approach used by other databases such as PostgreSQL.

Comment: This "approach" is used by all (standard compliant) databases, not only Postgres